# Using variables with grep is not working

Tags: shell, grep

I have a file VALIDATION_CONFIG_FILE.cfg which contains the records below:

```
ES_VDF_1|1
DE_VDF_1|2
ES_VDF_1|7
```

When I am using the `grep` command below by using variable then the command is returning `ES_VDF_1` output. As per my understanding, command should not give any results. When I use the same command without using variables (use values directly) then command is returning no results, which is as expected. So what is the problem with variables which I am using?

```
FEED_ID_1_7="HU_VDF_1"
FEED_ID_2_7="ES_VDF_1"
FEED_ID_3_7="PT_VDF_2"

awk -F'|' '{ if($2=="7") print $1; }' VALIDATION_CONFIG_FILE.cfg |
grep -E -v '${FEED_ID_1_7}|${FEED_ID_2_7}|${FEED_ID_3_7}'
```

Output: `ES_VDF_1`

```
awk -F'|' '{ if($2=="7") print $1; }' VALIDATION_CONFIG_FILE.cfg |
grep -E -v 'ES_VDF_1|HU_VDF_1|PT_VDF_2'
```

Output: *nothing*

Comment: Hi Jonathan...I have edited the question

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  Please delete your comment, and flag this one as obsolete (in case I don't get to delete it).

Comment: This `awk -F'|' '{ if($2=="7") print $1; }' VALIDATION_CONFIG_FILE.cfg` can be shorten some `awk -F\ '$2=="7" {print $1}' VALIDATION_CONFIG_FILE.cfg`

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are seeing is that single quotes in Bash do not interpolate variables, whereas double quotes do.

For example with a variable imaginatively called "VARIABLE":

```
alex@yuzu:~$ export VARIABLE="foo"
```

If you echo it with double quotes, it is interpolated and the value of the variable is used:

```
alex@yuzu:~$ echo "$VARIABLE"
foo
```

But if you use single quotes the literal string '$VARIABLE' is used instead:

```
alex@yuzu:~$ echo '$VARIABLE'
$VARIABLE
```

The same goes for your grep.

```
grep -E -v '${FEED_ID_1_7}|${FEED_ID_2_7}|${FEED_ID_3_7}'
```

Should be:

```
grep -E -v "${FEED_ID_1_7}\|${FEED_ID_2_7}\|${FEED_ID_3_7}"
```

---

For example:

```
alex@yuzu:~$ echo "foo" | grep -E "$VARIABLE|$HOME|$USER"
foo

alex@yuzu:~$ echo "foo" | grep -E '$VARIABLE|$HOME|$USER'
[ no output ]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening due to quotes.

Single quotes won't interpolate anything, but double quotes will do. Replace single quotes to double quotes with variables like below :

```
awk -F'|' '{ if($2=="7") print $1; }' VALIDATION_CONFIG_FILE.cfg |
grep -E -v "${FEED_ID_1_7}|${FEED_ID_2_7}|${FEED_ID_3_7}"
```

Refer [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Kaoru/Nishu Tayal's answer, you can make it safer further by using normal text search with `fgrep` and multiple `-e`:

```
fgrep -v -e "${FEED_ID_1_7}" -e "${FEED_ID_2_7}" -e "${FEED_ID_3_7}"
```

This would help prevent misinterpretations just in case special characters would be added to the values of variables.

If you don't have `fgrep` try `grep -F`.